# How to get source of an object instance with dynamic method?

Tags: ruby, pry

I could get source code of a class using Pry.

```
[1] pry(main)> class AAA
[1] pry(main)*   def aaa
[1] pry(main)*     "111"
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> Pry.WrappedModule(AAA).source
=> "class AAA\n  def aaa\n    \"111\"\n  end\nend\n"
[3] pry(main)>
```

Is it possible to get a source code of an object with dynamically added method? I tried some, but I couldn't get the source.

```
[1] pry(main)> class AAA
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> a = AAA.new
=> #<AAA:0x007fe3de0c0570>
[3] pry(main)> cd a
[4] pry(#<AAA>):1> def aaa
[4] pry(#<AAA>):1*   "111"
[4] pry(#<AAA>):1* end  
=> nil
[5] pry(#<AAA>):1> cd ..
[6] pry(main)> Pry.WrappedModule(a)
ArgumentError: Tried to initialize a WrappedModule with a non-module #<AAA:0x007fe3de0c0570>
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.2/lib/pry/wrapped_module.rb:59:in `initialize'
[7] pry(main)> Pry.WrappedModule(a).source
ArgumentError: Tried to initialize a WrappedModule with a non-module #<AAA:0x007fe3de0c0570>
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.9.12.2/lib/pry/wrapped_module.rb:59:in `initialize'
[8] pry(main)> Pry.WrappedModule(AAA)
=> #<Pry::WrappedModule:0x007fe3dd938820
 @doc=nil,
 @host_file_lines=nil,
 @memoized_candidates=[],
 @source=nil,
 @source_location=nil,
 @wrapped=AAA>
[9] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Do you want to get file name of the class definition?

Answer (score 0):

when you want to look into ruby code, you will have to get the abstract syntax tree (AST) of the class. there are some libraries like ripper, ruby2ruby, sorcerer that might help you with that.

i don't think that it is possible to get to the "source" of a generated method as it basically has no source.

Comment: @banister unfortunately does not work for methods created through eval `MethodSource::SourceNotFoundError: Cannot open "(eval)" for reading.`

Comment: no, but it works for methods created dynamically in the Pry REPL (which is what he was trying to do, afaict)

Comment: @banister if you are sure that this is not just an example, then yeah go ahead and post it as an answer!